# Filtering access logs by last 15 minutes with awk not working when there are no entries

Tags: linux, apache, logging, awk

I have an apache access log with the below format and I'm trying to use the awk command to filter out the requests by the last 15 minutes. It works fine when there are entries but returns everything when there are none found in the last 15 minutes.

```
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-15 minute' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $9}' access.log
```

Access log format

```
10.185.248.71 - - [09/Jan/2015:19:12:06 +0000] 808840 "GET /inventoryService/inventory/purchaseItem?userId=20253471&itemId=23434300 HTTP/1.1" 500 17 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)"
```

Comment: fwiw, `awk` is going to do the comparison as strings, and the datetime format you're dealing with is not going to work (eg, `13/Jan/2015` > `03/Dec/2021` will evaluate as true); for comparing strings you'll need to convert the date/time values to `YYYY/MM/DD:24H:MM:SS` (use whatever delimiter floats your boat) or jump through some hoops to convert all date/time values to seconds-since-epoch and then compare the resulting integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to compare date directly in bash or in awk... but you can compare dates transformed into integers...

```sh
#! /bin/bash

BEFORE=$(date -d 'now-15 minute' +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

awk \
    -v before="${BEFORE}" \
    '
    function toComparableDate (date) {
        # 000000000111111111122
        # 123456789012345678901
        # [09/Jan/2015:19:12:06
        return substr(date,9,4) hMonth[substr(date,5,3)] substr(date,2,2) substr(date,14,2) substr(date,17,2) substr(date,20,2)
    }
    BEGIN {
        hMonth["Jan"] = "01"
        hMonth["Feb"] = "02"
        hMonth["Mar"] = "03"
        hMonth["Apr"] = "04"
        hMonth["May"] = "05"
        hMonth["Jun"] = "06"
        hMonth["Jul"] = "07"
        hMonth["Aug"] = "08"
        hMonth["Oct"] = "09"
        hMonth["Sep"] = "10"
        hMonth["Nov"] = "11"
        hMonth["Dec"] = "12"
    }
    toComparableDate($4) > before {
        print $8
    }
    ' \
    "$1"
```

Executed like that:

```sh
./apachelogs.sh access.log
```

Comment: Typo in the November key but works a treat! Thanks!

Comment: @David Armstrong, fixed. Thanks